# iOS : View visible but not active

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios

I got a `UIViewController` that init a `UIView`.
This view containing Interactive Elements like `UITextField` or `UIButton`.
View is added on ViewDidLoad, at the bottom of the method to be sure that when I made it visible it can be reach by user interaction.

But when I show the view, no interaction can be done on this View.

Is this only possible? Am I doing something wrong?

```
The View
public class AddBusinessEventView : UIView
{
    public UILabel LblTitle;
    public UITextField TxtType;
    public UIButton BtnClose;

    public AddBusinessEventView(nfloat bw, nfloat bh)
    {


        //Bouton pour fermer le popup
        BtnClose = new UIButton();
        BtnClose.SetImage(UIImage.FromFile("Images/Boutons/lightbox_close.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
        BtnClose.Frame = new CGRect(bw - 80, 30, BtnFermer.ImageView.Image.CGImage.Width * 0.5, BtnFermer.ImageView.Image.CGImage.Height * 0.5);

        //Doit se trouver par dessus txtSite et ajouté après dans la vue pour se trouvé en premier plan

        LblTitle = new UILabel();
        LblTitle.Frame = new CGRect((bw - (lw + 200)) / 2, 100, lw + 200, 30);
        LblTitle.Text = "Fill with your event elements";
        LblTitle.Font = UIFont.FromName("GillSans-Bold", 22);
        LblTitle.TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB(211, 3, 67);
        LblTitle.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;

        TxtType = new UITextField(new CGRect((bw - 750) / 2, 140, 350, 40));
        TxtType.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        TxtType.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        TxtType.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect;
        TxtType.AutocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No;
        TxtType.AutocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.AllCharacters;
        TxtType.Placeholder = "Type";

        AddSubviews(BtnClose, LblTitle, TxtType);
    }
}
```

The UIViewController

```
partial class EvenementViewController : EnhancedUIViewController
{
    AddBusinessEventView AddBusinessEventView;

    public EvenementViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) { }

    public EvenementViewController() : base() { }

    public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
        if (myEvent == null)
        {
            ShowAddBusinessEventView();
        }
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        nfloat bw = View.Bounds.Width;
        nfloat bh = View.Bounds.Height;
        //Another Elements are adding to view here
        //...

        AddBusinessEventView = new AddBusinessEventView(bw, bh);
        AddBusinessEventView.Hidden = true;

        //Much more View.Add with all elements here
        //...

        View.Add(AddBusinessEventView);
        AddBusinessEventView.BtnType.TouchUpInside += BtnClose_TouchUpInside;
    }

    #region BusinessEventAdd
    void ShowAddBusinessEventView()
    {
        UIView.Animate(duration: 1,
            delay: 0,
            options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut,
            animation: () =>
            {
                AddBusinessEventView.Alpha = 1.0f;
            },
            completion: () =>
            {
                AddBusinessEventView.Hidden = false;
                AddBusinessEventListener();
            }

        );
    }

    void HideAddBusinessEventView()
    {
        UIView.Animate(duration: 1,
            delay: 0,
            options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut,
            animation: () =>
            {
                AddBusinessEventView.Alpha = 0.0f;
            },
            completion: () =>
            {
                AddBusinessEventView.Hidden = true;
                RemoveBusinessEventListener();
            }

        );
    }

    void BtnClose_TouchUpInside(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Touching myself");
    }
    #endregion
}
```

please concidere EnhancedViewController as standard UIViewController, I'm juste adding some enhancements to show users a message from an Overlay.

As I said, we can't interact neither with TxtType nor BtnClose.

Edit : 
Don't sure if it can help; but when the `View` is added to the Main `View` on the `UIViewController`, it display well, but all user interaction are catches on element under this `View`
i.e : The `AddBusinessEventView` act as a popup, so it covered all other element, when i press an element, if another element adding prior of this `View` is under, it's this element rather than the `AddBusinessEventView` element that catch the touch event.

As said, the main purpose is to cut View element on different file for more readability and maintenability of this application.`enter code here`

Comment: I couldn't see any addSubview method on  the label, button and textfield.  Not sure in Xamarin, but in pure iOS, you would need to add every new view to a parent view...

Comment: You're right, I cut it off when I clear the code, you can conceder it was here.

Comment: You're talking about pure iOS, is it something that we can do in xcode/Swift? I mean, can we get multiple UIView with some interactive elements on it and adding them into the UIViewController? So we could cut your code into View/ViewController files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason you can't do that.
You can architect your code like

- UIViewController

  - Controller1
  - Controller2
  - ...
- Views

  - View1
  - View2
  - ...

And then use View1 and View2 in any of Controller.

I tried your code and I got all the things popup correctly.
As you said, if view show up on screen but it's element from another View from below that interact with user maybe you can try to bring your View to front.

Try this

```
View.BringSubviewToFront(AddBusinessEventView);
```

At the end of your ViewDidLoad function.

Comment: Is there any reason that it not coming back to front when i added it last to the View?

Comment: It's not working, i can't touch the button that it's into the subview

Comment: Sorry for the long absence before answering. Did you try to set the Frame Size to your View, if the view is correctly added, and you think that it is on the top. It can be a size matter. The main contanier for your view may not take full space and not handling touch because of that.

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot Leze, I let this project in standby since, you save my day